# Выбор выпадающего списка сайта C#

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, webbrowser

Доброго времени суток, гуру.

Вот такой у меня появился вопрос. Нужно создать генератор с автозаполнением форм, но ума не приложу что делать с выпадающими списками. Как можно их открывать и выбирать через, допустим, кнопку? Если есть идеи, поделитесь пожалуйста

Заранее благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, речь идет об элементе `<select>`. В таком случае, как вариант, можно использовать кастомный контрол, который предоставляет api: open, select. Как вариант Kendojs либо что-то свое.